# Image colorization using Keras - val_loss oscillates

Tags: tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have this sequential model:

```
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 256, 256, 32)      320
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      18496
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       73856
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 256)       295168
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 128)       295040
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTran (None, 64, 64, 128)       147584
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 64)        73792
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTr (None, 128, 128, 64)      36928
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 128, 32)      18464
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, 256, 256, 32)      9248
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 16)      4624
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 2)       290
=================================================================
```

And i want to colorize black and white (256x256) portraits.
My dataset size: 7650
[image: accuracy]
[image: loss]

I tried to use Adamax and RMSprop. Accuracy and loss is OK, but val_loss and val_accuracy just oscillates.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your model is [**overfitting**](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit), you should **reduce the number of parameters** in your network : less weight layers or less filters.

Additionnaly, you can use **techniques** to reduce overfitting : Dropout, BatchNormalization, regularization...

Finally, you can create new images with **data augmentation** (according to your dataset) like images flip, shift, rotation, crop ...